# How to loop array of arrays and chunk in equals parts?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of arrays which I'm looping to save data.

The problem is sometimes the array is very large.

I would like to loop this array until a limit.

Once it passes that limit, it should calculate how much it has left to finish looping through all arrays, chunk it and finish it.

```
foreach ($offers as $offer){
    //If have more the 8.000 then make more then one array_objects
    $object_offer = new Offer();
    $object_offer->setOfferSellerId($offer['sku']);
    $object_offer->setQuantity($offer['quantity']);
    $object_offers[] = $object_offer;
    $i++;
    if (count($offers) <= 8000 ){
        if ($i >= count($offers)){
            $this->invokeUpdateStockOffer($object_offers);
        }
    } else {
        //Chunk it in some ways and save
        $this->invokeUpdateStockOffer($object_offers);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Hi Gache, it sounds like you want to execute the offers in batches of 8000, is this correct?

Comment: check this out [array_chunk php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can batch up your offers into groups of 8000 using the PHP `array_chunk` method
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

For example, you have an array with 8 values `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and you want to have them grouped into batches of 2.

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 2);
```

Now the `$chunked` variable will contain 4 arrays.

```
[
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [5,6],
    [7,8],
]
```

This is what you will want to do so you can batch the offers into manageable blocks. You can then iterate over each 8000 block and update the stock offers after each chunk.

```
<?php
// Chunk the offers into batches of 8000
$batches = array_chunk($offers, 8000);
// Iterate over each chunk
foreach ($batches as $batchOffers) {
    // Process the offers and store them in the array
    $objectOffers = [];
    foreach ($batchOffers as $offer) {
         $objectOffer = new Offer();
         $objectOffer->setOfferSellerId($offer['sku']);
         $objectOffer->setQuantity($offer['quantity']);
         $objectOffers[] = $objectOffer;
    }
    // Update the offers
    $this->invokeUpdateStockOffer($objectOffers);
}
```